# Intermittent hint noexpand is invalid

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have some XMPP servers running on Linux that uses FreeTDS to connect to an MS SQL 2014 database server to load rosters. Loading rosters is a select on a indexed view and the select uses the noexpand hint and look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.[vIdxRosterUsers] WITH (NOEXPAND)
WHERE jid = 'alpha.4663@localhost'
```

Intermittenly we will get errors on our XMPP server logs like this:

> [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Hint 'noexpand' on object 'dbo.vIdxRosterUsers'
>   is invalid.

It happens maybe one out of 10000 queries.

Does anyone have an idea of why SQL server would intermittenly complain about using the noexpand hint on an indexed view?

Adding source code for the view and its index:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vIdxRosterUsers] 
WITH schemabinding 
AS 
  SELECT 'fr.' + Cast(f.actorid AS VARCHAR)       AS username, 
         'fr.' + Cast(f.friendactorid AS VARCHAR) 
         + '@localhost'                           AS jid, 
         'fr.' + Cast(f.friendactorid AS VARCHAR) AS nick, 
         'B'                                      AS subscription, 
         'N'                                      AS ask, 
         ''                                       AS askmessage, 
         'N'                                      AS server, 
         ''                                       AS subscribe, 
         'item'                                   AS type 
  FROM   dbo.friend f 
  WHERE  f.status = 2 
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_rosterusers_user_jid] 
  ON [dbo].[vIdxRosterUsers] ( [username] ASC, [jid] ASC ) 
  WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO
```

Comment: can you provide source of your view?

Comment: I have added the source to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Is the index being removed intermittently? Maybe as a broken defrag strategy? And does dbo.[vIdxRosterUsers] always refer to an indexed view or is there runtime renaming going on?

Comment: Also, I don't think you need an indexed view here at all. Create the appropriate/equivalent index and it's going to be just as fast.

Comment: This also happens during the day when we are not running any index maintenance jobs. Could SQL server do defrag all by itself as some kind of option?

We have tried to not use an indexed view and just hit the underlying friend table with an index directly on that table, and that lead to awful performance.

Answer (score 1):

For this view dbo.[vIdxRosterUsers] kindly **create a unique(clustered or non clustered) index** for this or column **jid** in order to run the query. Point to note is that the indexed column on table and the indexed column on the view are completely separate, having an indexed tabled but a view that is no indexed will result to noexpand is invalid

Answer (score 0):

a small idea... drop view, add computed column and filtered index

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.friend
    ADD jid AS 'fr.' + CAST(f.friendactorid AS VARCHAR(20)) + '@localhost' PERSISTED    
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_rosterusers_user_jid] 
  ON dbo.friend ([username], [jid]) WHERE f.[status] = 2 
  WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO
```